# Выпадающее меню уходит за блок bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url(FonCar.png);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7em;
  background: transparent;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #1D1E22;
}

.shapka {
  height: 250px;
}

.car {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 375px;
  left: 23%;
  top: -60px;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -25%;
}

.logotable {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 55px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.zagolovok {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Impact;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bg-light {
  opacity: 0.92;
}

.content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.footer {
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D1E22;
  margin: 0;
}

.labelincontent {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина */
  text-align: left;
  /* Выравниваем по правому краю */
  background: #1D1E22;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: white;
}

ul.hr li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

p,
h2,
h3 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.logomobile {}

ul.hrmobile li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.input {
  border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.shapka .col-md .col-sm {
  display: none;
}

.next {
  color: black;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  /* Убираем границу */
  background-color: gray;
  /* Цвет линии */
  height: 1px;
  /* Толщина линии */
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.map-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.map-responsive iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">BARS</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse opacity-0.5" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active border-right-0">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Виды ремонта
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Услуги автосервиса</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ремонт гибридов</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Компьютерная диагностика</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Сервисное обслуживание</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ремонт инжектора</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ремонт двигателя</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="kakproexat.html">Как проехать</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#obratsv" href="#">Обратная связь</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-lg-none d-xs-block">
        <a class="nav-link ">Телефон:+79069960426</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-lg-none d-xs-block">
        <a class="nav-link ">Адрес: Русская,35</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

У меня уходит выпадающее меню за блок. Что и как поделать, не знаю.
Прилагаю скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У этого блока где-то задан `overflow: hidden;`. Без ваших КТС точнее не подскажу)

Comment: КТС? Что это , или вы имели ввиду css?

Comment: @Martix, да, речь именно о css. Но, в представленном участке ничего не говорит о проблеме, так как он вырван из контекста. Если есть ссылка на ваш пример в исходном виде, это сразу решит вопрос.

Comment: Сегодня скину ссылку на сам сайт

Comment: http://l37-195-222-8.novotelecom.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нижний блок перекрывает объекты из верхнего блока с меню. `z-index` нужно применять именно для родителя, а не выпадающего списка.

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень сильно помог!

Answer (score 0):

Задай z-index: 1000 выпадающему списку. Но чтобы сказать точнее нужен твой css-код.

Comment: Выложил весь css код.